# Kafka MirrorMaker - Deletion of a topic is not replicated

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have setup MirrorMaker2 to replicate 2 Apache Kafka clusters. Everything seems to work smoothly.
My only issue is that when deleting a **topic** from **CLUSTER1** (that is replicated as **CLUSTER1.topic** on cluster2, the replicated topic **CLUSTER1.topic** on cluster2 is not deleted.
So it seems that the deletion of a topic is not replicated to the other cluster. There is some specific property that controls the replication of deletion of a topic on mm2.properties?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. MirrorMaker2 does not delete topics or groups.

There are a few reasons:

- This prevents losing data in case of a topic is deleted by mistake. In that case, the copy on the remote cluster is still available.
- Clusters can be operated/used by different teams. A team not needing a topic anymore does not necessarily it's not needed anymore on the remote cluster too.
- Kafka does not track "ownership" (who created it) of topics. It's possible for a topic with a name matching MirrorMaker2 rules to exist on a remote cluster without it being a MirrorMaker2 replica.

To avoid any of these issues, currently (this can be changed if the community agrees), MirrorMaker2 does not delete resources on remote clusters.